# How to make horizontal linechart with categorical variables and timeseries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to replicate plots from this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5000555/pdf/nihms774453.pdf I'm particularly interested in plot on page 16, right panel. I tried to do this in matplotlib but it seems to me that there is no way to access lines in linecollection.

I don't know how to change the color of the each line, according to the value at every index. I'd like to eventually get something like here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html but for every line, according to the data.

this is what I tried:

the data in numpy array: https://pastebin.com/B1wJu9Nd

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

%matplotlib inline




base_range = np.arange(qq.index.max()+1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.set_xlim(qq.index.min(), qq.index.max())
# ax.set_ylim(qq.columns[0], qq.columns[-1])
ax.set_ylim(-5, len(qq.columns) +5)

line_segments = LineCollection([np.column_stack([base_range, [y]*len(qq.index)]) for y in range(len(qq.columns))],
                               cmap='viridis',
                               linewidths=(5),
                               linestyles='solid', 

                              )
line_segments.set_array(base_range)
ax.add_collection(line_segments)
axcb = fig.colorbar(line_segments)
plt.show()
```

my result: 
[image: my result]

what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You need to stick to the example. There is a `norm` which you removed here, but which is important because it normalizes the data into the 0..1 range for the colormap.

Comment: but norm is not changing anything special in my experiments. could you elaborate how to use it?

Comment: Just as in the example you link to

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't really a useful problem description; especially since I don't know the actual code that doesn't work for you. If you can provide a [mcve] (runnable self-contained code), I can look further into this.